# for loop in data frame in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and I would like to ask what is wrong in the following simple command. When i try:

```
   for (k in 1:1){
  logdata= logDataset[1:74+k,k]}
```

logdata collects the values from rows 2:75 of column 1 of the logDataset data frame. But when I use:

```
logdata=logDataset[1:75,1]
```

logdata collects correctly the first 75 values of the first column. Why the first command does not work as the second one? How can I use the "for" command for collecting the first 75 values of the first column? Many thanks.

Comment: Type `1:74+1` in your command line. It first creates a sequence from 1 to 74, and then adds one to every element of the sequence. You should do `1:(74+k)` or `seq(1,74+k)`

Comment: Use `1:(74+k)` in your code. Nevertheless, you are building a for loop for just one execution of your code. Is it really useful?

Comment: @Florian oh....I see..1:(74+k) works. Thank you vert much Florian!

Comment: @R18 Thank you R18. I know that it looks stupid but I just tried to simplify my question. Thanks guys.